# google analytics api data does not match to the actual data on my account

Tags: php, google-analytics

I am using the google analytics api in php. When I want to get the details of event levels like total events and unique events it gives inaccurate values. When I use my google analytics account (website) I get the right values. This is the code I use to retrieve the events:

```
$optParams = array(
    'dimensions' => 'ga:eventcategory,ga:eventaction,'.
        'ga:eventlabel,ga:source,ga:devicecategory',
    'filters' => 'ga:eventcategory==category name,'.
        'ga:eventaction==event name',
    'start-index' => $start_index,
    'max-results' => $limit
);

$results = $analytics->data_ga->get(
    'ga:' . $this->ga_api_profileId,
    $start_date,
    $end_date,
    'ga:totalEvents,ga:uniqueEvents',
    $optParams
);
```

Comment: I presumed this is what you were trying to say. Feel free to revert if you think I changed the content incorrectly.

Comment: Ok, I want to say that i am passing the above dimensions and metrics to get the data like page views through an event which is already created on my ga account, but the result which comes from these values doesn't match to the values on my ga account.

Comment: your looking at data that's more then 2 days old right?

Comment: yes. but if i look for today only then it also gives wrong data.